# What's the difference between using select + unlist from dplyr package and using the dollar sign?

Tags: r, dplyr

I've been taking an online course in which the instructor always does the following to obtain, say, the column `Col1` from a `data.frame` object `Dat`:

```
library(dplyr)
unlist(select(Dat, Col1))
```

Why not simply run `Dat$Col1`? I notice a difference in the "presentation" of both results, but is there any other significant divergence between the two forms? Any operation will result in the same product for both?

Comment: Your instructor is probably just a fan of the tidyverse.  `Dat$Col1` is my preferred method for getting a column.

Comment: ...but not well-`verse`d enough to know of `pull`.

Comment: Touche.  Maybe OP can take the instructor to school.

Comment: Wow, he loads an entire new library for that?

Comment: The rumours about the SO incident `spread`, and the instructor decided to `gather` `every` student. `today` he had started to `select` cigarettes without `filter`, and took a long, deep `pull` to `compose` himself for a `minute`. It was a mare’s `nest`. “Well, I have a crow to `pluck` with you, `who` did this?”, the teacher started. "`between` you and me: this is _no_ `funs`. You better not `cross` me, or I will `reduce` your grades, `every` grade. Whichever way you `slice` it - `period`!" The students looked at each other. A `complete` farce. Happy new `year` `every` one - `tally`-ho!

Comment: @Henrik you should get yourself a place in the `fortunes`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

(Posting comments as community wiki.)

These are not *quite* equivalent - `unlist(select(.))` keeps (probably unwanted) names.

```
dd <- data.frame(Col1=c("abc","def"))
str(unlist(select(dd,Col1)))
##  Factor w/ 2 levels "abc","def": 1 2
##  - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "Col11" "Col12"
str(dd$Col1)
##  Factor w/ 2 levels "abc","def": 1 2
```

Your instructor is probably just a fan of the [tidyverse](https://www.tidyverse.org/) (@RichScriven); `pull(Dat, Col1)` or (for extreme "tidiness") `Dat %>% pull(Col1)` would be more idiomatic (@Henrik). `Dat$Col1` or `Dat[["Col1"]]` would be the base-R equivalents (the former is more convenient for interactive use, the latter is marginally safer for programming purposes since it won't do name-completion).

It hardly matters, but the tidyverse approaches are much slower.

```
microbenchmark(dd$Col1,dd[["Col1"]],pull(dd,Col1),unlist(select(dd,Col1)))
Unit: microseconds
                     expr     min        lq       mean    median       uq
                  dd$Col1   5.296   10.9630   14.86871   13.4040   17.160
             dd[["Col1"]]   7.870    9.6535   15.18874   11.8270   16.635
           pull(dd, Col1)  44.160  108.7625  128.89342  117.8415  136.890
 unlist(select(dd, Col1)) 601.480 1132.8240 1436.44178 1214.4420 1378.141
      max neval cld
   31.036   100  a 
   88.842   100  a 
  422.462   100  a 
 8796.964   100   b
```

Comment: Since you mentioned it, `pull(dd, Col1)` is twice as fast as `dd %>% pull(Col1)`. Tested with a much larger `dd <- data.frame(Col1 = sample(c("abc", "def"), 1e6, TRUE))`.

Comment: Just to note, there's always the use.names argument to the base R function, `unlist` which will drop any unwanted names: `unlist(select(.), use.names=FALSE)`.